# Upgrading virtual box Windows 8 to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my virtual box Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 but am getting the following message.

"Your pc doesn't have enough space to install windows 8.1. Make more space available on your drive and try again"

This is a virtual machine that has a dynamically allocated hard drive size. The host machine has over 300GB free space.

How can I let the machine think it has more space so it will upgrade?

Comment: How much free space does the virtual machine have.  You have to extend the partition.

Comment: @Ramhound At the moment the HD is dynamically allocated. How can I increase the partition size?

Comment: Its a two step process.  The first you have to use the Vbox tools to increase the size of the hdd.  The second depending on the guest os, you then extend the size of the actual partition, my question in my comment is important.

Comment: From computer the free space it is showing is 1.77GB